# Create regex to isolate tags?

Tags: javascript, tags

How could I achieve something like this?

```
example_input = "hi, this is example #input, it has a few #different things going #on. #question"

output ===> [input, different, on, question]
```

This is what I have so far:

```
text.match(/\#.+?\s+/g)
```

I've be able to get to isolation when followed by white space but I'm not sure how to adapt for `,` `' '` `.` or `string end / new line`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/#\w+\b/g
```

\b for boundary characters

for spaces, commas, and string ends
use '\s', ',' and '$'

```
/#\w+(\s?|.|$)/g
```

here is a list of special characters you can use (read under special characters):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: I'm getting null or undefined for every match.

Comment: fixed it, I had forgotten the g tag

Comment: What if I only wanted to limit it to spaces, commas, and string ends?

Answer (score 0):

This will start matching at the # and go until either a space or punctuation is found.

```
/#[^\s\p{P}]+/
```

Comment: This keeps terminating punctuation in the match, but doesn't keep terminating spaces. Is there anyway to standardize this?

Comment: this will return an array of all the matches in your string: var matches="hi, this is example #input, it has a few #different things going #on. #question".match(/#[^\s\p{P}]+/g);

Comment: What if I only wanted to limit it to spaces, commas, and string ends?

Comment: You could replace the \p{P} with what you wanted to stop on.  The \s already stops on spaces - so your regex would be something like /#[^\s,$]+/g.  Though, the $ sign seems somewhat redundant to me.